# How think about column value decide to refer table in mysql

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.6, table

I'm designing table relationship.

I have an one question.

An Example)

Some customer want to contract car or bike.

Customer must contract an one only.

I'm thinking for this case table relationship.

1.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contract` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '[ID]',
  `no` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '[NO]',
  `type` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '[contract target]..1:car,2:bike',
  `type_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '[target table id]',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

2.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contract` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '[ID]',
  `no` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '[NO]',
  `car_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '[car table id]',
  `bike_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '[bike table id]',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

car, bike table primary key is id.

---

case 1.

If type value is 1. Refer car table. 2 is bike table.

This case can't set foreign key constraint.
but size is smaller than case2.

case 2.

If contract target is car. bike_id column value is 0.

---

If you have a idea Please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: Record size is (4+(20+1)+1+4)+6+7=43 bytes for case 1 and 46 bytes for case 2. Do you really think that 7% size save (without taking into account the block granularity) is better than FK constraint existence?

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your reply. I choose case 2!